# Virtualbox machine failed to find graphics directx 9.0c support

Tags: virtualbox, graphics-card

I tried to install "The Sims 2 Open For Business" on my VirtualBox guest machine and got the below error snapshot.

How can I get it fix?

[image]

**Update**

Enabling the 3D and 2D display hardware acceleration will get the below error snapshot

[image]

Comment: [Install guest extensions and enable experimental hardware acceleration Support](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-3d)

Comment: well, it is experimental for a reason..